# Multiple Numpy random shuffles does not add up

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate an array of neighbors, each neighbor differing from the previous neighbor in one random shuffle, either a row or column shuffle. The neighbors should only be generated if a certain row or column has more than K 1's, and if so, a neighbor should be generated with this row or column shuffled. The shuffles should be additive, meaning that if first a row is shuffled and then a column; two neighbors should be generated, one with a shuffled row and one with both a row and a column shuffled.

However, it seems that the array is only shuffled two times, one for the column loop and one for the row loop, and the shuffles don't add up.

In this example, column index 1 and 2 should be shuffled, and row index 3 and 4. Here is an example output, showing the generated neighbors:.

```
[[0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1]]

[[0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1]]

[[0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1]]

[[0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
```

Here is the code:

```
k=2
tmp = np.array([
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
,[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
,[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
,[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
,[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    ])

board = np.copy(tmp)
column = np.sum(board, axis=0)-k
columns = len(column)
row = np.sum(board, axis=1)-k
rows = len(row)
neighbors = []

for i in range(columns):
    if column[i] > 0:
        np.random.shuffle(board[:,i])
        neighbors.append(np.copy(board))

for i in range(rows):
    if row[i] > 0:
        np.random.shuffle(board[i,:])
        neighbors.append(np.copy(board))

print tmp
print column
print row
for i in neighbors:
    print i
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works `:)`

It's just that sometimes a row or column is shuffled but stays in the same configuration. Compare with:

```
ar = np.array([0, 1])

for _ in range(10):
    print ar
    np.random.shuffle(ar)
```

In addition, it's not unlikely that the elements of a row or column are indeed shuffled, but you'll end up with ones and zeros in the exact same place anyway (because there's only a limited number of unique permutations).